# Changing/Adding RAM to my Vaio

Tags: memory, sony-vaio

I have a [Vaio VPCCW2S1E](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vn-cw-series/vpccw2s1e-w) that apparently has PC3-8500 , 1066Mhz DDR3 SDRAM memory. I'd like to change/add memory (go from 4GB to 8GB), and when searching in Amazon I saw that there are many PC3-8500 models but "for Macbook". I was wondering if it's the same thing or not?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the memory is 1066Mhz DDR3 SDRAM and respects the hardware limits of your Vaio (8GB), they should work. MacBooks use the same kind of memory that non-apple notebooks use.

When I added RAM to my MacBook Pro for example, I only searched for the memory size and speed (8GB and 1066Mhz in your case).

Yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: so if I add 2 8GB sticks it will only recognize 8?

Comment: You can't add 8GB sticks -- the maximum supported memory density is 512MBx64 which gives 4GB per slot.

Comment: No, as David said the maximum supported are 2 sticks of 4GB each, which gives you the maximum 8GB your Vaio support.